# Python: ctypes pointer to local variables; how to ensure they don't get freed?

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

I have some code somewhat similar to this:

```
def castArgToCtype(arg, ctyp):
    if issubclass(ctyp, _ctypes._Pointer): return createPtr(arg, ctyp)
    return ctyp(arg)

def createPtr(arg, ctyp):
    assert isinstance(arg, (list,tuple))
    assert issubclass(ctyp, _ctypes._Pointer)
    o = (ctyp._type_ * (len(arg) + 1))()
    for i in xrange(len(arg)):
        o[i] = castArgToCtype(arg[i], ctyp._type_)
    op = ctypes.cast(ctypes.addressof(o), ctyp)
    # TODO: what when 'o' goes out of scope and freed?
    return op
```

And I am calling it like `createPtr((1,2,3), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))`.

How can I ensure that the ctpes array `o` I create there is not freed as long as `op` is not freed?

I have seen the attribute `op._objects` which even seem to be there for this purpose but it is readonly.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Why do you think this is necessary?

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: What exactly is your question? My question is, how can I ensure that `o` (or the underlying ctypes memory block) is not freed after `createPtr` returns.

Comment: With the above code, it probably gets freed. Thus, at some point, you probably will get a segfault. Of course you want to avoid that.

Comment: Just wondering why `o=(ctypes.c_int*3)(1,2,3)` isn't sufficient?

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: Because in my case, I need a `POINTER(c_int)` to it. See [here](https://github.com/albertz/PyCPython) if you are interested in what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
import ctypes, _ctypes

def castArgToCtype(arg, ctyp):
    if issubclass(ctyp, _ctypes._Pointer): return createPtr(arg, ctyp)
    return ctyp(arg)

def createPtr(arg, ctyp):
    assert isinstance(arg, (list,tuple))
    assert issubclass(ctyp, _ctypes._Pointer)
    o = (ctyp._type_ * (len(arg) + 1))()
    for i in xrange(len(arg)):
        o[i] = castArgToCtype(arg[i], ctyp._type_)
    op = ctypes.pointer(o)
    op = ctypes.cast(op, ctyp)
    return op

a = createPtr((1,2,3), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
print a, a[0], a[1], a[2], a._objects
```

Output:

```
<__main__.LP_c_int object at 0x105dc6680> 1 2 3 {'1': <__main__.c_int_Array_4 object at 0x105dc6560>, '0': {}, 4393297392: <__main__.LP_c_int_Array_4 object at 0x105dc65f0>}
```

Answer (score 0):

The extra iteration is not needed.  Just create the array object and cast it to the pointer required.

```
import ctypes,_ctypes
def castArgToCtype(arg, ctyp):
    if issubclass(ctyp, _ctypes._Pointer): return createPtr(arg, ctyp)
    return ctyp(arg)

def createPtr(arg, ctyp):
    assert isinstance(arg, (list,tuple))
    assert issubclass(ctyp, _ctypes._Pointer)
    return ctypes.cast((ctyp._type_ * len(arg))(*arg),ctyp)

a = castArgToCtype((1,2,3),ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
print a,a[0],a[1],a[2],a._objects
```

#### Output

```
<x.LP_c_long object at 0x00EB7760> 1 2 3 {15431440: <ctypes._endian.c_long_Array_3 object at 0x00EB7710>}
```

Comment: Not in the case `createPtr((1,2,3), POINTER(c_int))` but what about `createPtr(((1,2),(2,3),(3,4)), POINTER(POINTER(c_int)))`?